# Rails4 JSON Parameters Parse error while Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building API for Android using RoR, I am getting the Parameters for creating an object from Android is like below,

```
{"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}", "location"=>"Bangalore", "display_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb12dfa8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141119-6448-ewg4bk>, @original_filename="Male-Face-A1-icon.png", @content_type="image/*", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"display_photo\"; filename=\"Male-Face-A1-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/*\r\nContent-Length: 15460\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}
```

But this line giving error when parsing

```
"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"
```

Because, It should be like this for Rails,

```
"company"=>{"description":"Description of the company","name":"Google"}
```

How to achieve this in Rails...

Refer this link where Android is requesting to Rails Server,
[Android Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010183/in-android-is-there-any-way-to-send-a-json-object-as-multipart-so-ruby-and-rails)

Comment: What type of error you are getting once try `to_json` method in rails

Comment: I am doing this, puts JSON.parse({"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"}) Giving error as, TypeError (no implicit conversion of Hash into String):

Comment: If i do puts '{"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"}'.to_json OUT PUT: "{\"company\"=\u003e\"{\\\"description\\\":\\\"Description of the company\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Google\\\"}\"}"

Comment: puts `JSON.parse({"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"}.to_json)` check this output and let me know

Comment: @Choco, OUTPUT: {"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"}, Same thing no changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you params:

```
"company"=>
```

is a hash key

```
"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"
```

is a string, hash value

```
[2] pry(main)> JSON.parse "{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}"
=> {"description"=>"Description of the company", "name"=>"Google"}
```

gives correct output

Comment: Yes, but wanted to achieve for hole JSON where it coming from Android app, 

{"company"=>"{\"description\":\"Description of the company\",\"name\":\"Google\"}", "location"=>"Bangalore", "display_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb12dfa8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141119-6448-ewg4bk>, @original_filename="Male-Face-A1-icon.png", @content_type="image/*", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"display_photo\"; filename=\"Male-Face-A1-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/*\r\nContent-Length: 15460\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}

Comment: CODE STARTS
attrs = params.dup;
attrs[:company] = JSON.parse(params[:company]);
using modified attrs as params;
CODE ENDS
thats all